# Rails, Sphinx (thinking_sphinx) and sorting from associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have 3 models:

**Stats** (belongs_to :item)

```
  t.integer :skin_id
  t.integer :item_id
  t.integer :rating
```

**Item** (has_many :stats)

and

**Skin** (has_many :stats)

Using **thinking_sphinx** i want to create a separate index, for items, sorted by :rating for particular :skin_id

So, i'm trying to:

```
  define_index 'sort_by_rate' do
    indexes stats(:rating), :as => :ratings, :sortable => true
  end
```

But this, will generate an index for all :skin_id (in the Stat model), not for particular one.

In other words, i need to gather all items, sorted by Stat.rating, with Stat.skin_id == 1 (for example).

Here is the example of SQL:

```
"SELECT `stats`.* FROM `stats` INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `stats`.`item_id` WHERE `stats`.`skin_id` = 1 ORDER BY rating DESC"
```

ANy solutions is very appreciated!

Comment: How do you expect sorting Items by ratings to behave? There's multiple ratings per Item, so it's not clear on the behaviour you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have in your define_index block:

```
has :skin_id
```

and then, when searching, filter by that. Something like this:

```
Item.search(:with => {:skin_id => skin.id}, :order_by => 'ratings ASC')
```